# Display row at bottom of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

seem to be stuck on what should be a trivial task.  I have a section element like so

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-6">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Some Header</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row alignBottom">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Some more content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I have done is made this section the height of the viewport by doing

```
#about {
  background: #cccccc;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Now within this section I have two rows.  The first row should display at the top, so nothing I really need to do with this.  The second row I need to display at the bottom of the section.  To do this, I would have thought I would need to give the container a 100% height first, but this does not seem to change its height.  The only way I can get the container 100% is by using 100vh again, but seeing its a child of the section, why wouldnt 100% work?

Even when I do get it 100% using 100vh, I cant seem to get the row at the bottom of the container.  How would I go about doing this?

I have set up an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47yqopt5/)

Thanks

Comment: I'd play around with absolute positioning.

Comment: Can you add a scribble please? And do you want the footer element to scroll or should it be fixed on the bottom of the viewport, when scrolling through the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display:flex for this. From what i understood you want one of the rows to be display on the top of the section and other on the bottom

Div to have 100% height and width body should also need to have 100% width and height ,instead you can set 100vh height on about section and 100vh height on container

here is the snippet

```css
#about {
  background: #cccccc;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-6">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Some Header</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row alignBottom">
      <div class="col col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
        <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
        <p>Some more content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot.  I am trying to understand what makes the second row go to the bottom as I dont see anything specific in your example that does this.  Is it space-between?

Comment: yes display:flex and flex-direction:column makes both rows come on next line and justify-content:space-between does the magic of one row to be on the top and other to be on the bottom.check this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the position of the "alignBottom" row setting the correct "margin-top" at document ready:

The position of this row is: total height of the section minus the height of the row.

The snippet:

```js
$('.alignBottom').css('margin-top', $('#about').height() - $('.alignBottom').height());
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#about {
  background: #cccccc;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-6">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Some Header</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row alignBottom">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Some more content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```